# Mudar dados de user sem ele precisar de dar Logout / Login

Tags: php, mysql

Boas pessoal, creio que muita gente que trabalha com `PHP` já se deparou com esta minha questão que é: Quando eu edito algo no user ele nao edita logo, ou seja, tem que dar logout e fazer login para atribuir a sessão..

Passo a dar um exemplo:

Tenho uma **coluna** que é: `Nome` e ao atualiza-la ao user em questao, lhe mudava o nome apenas a dar F5 ou mudar para outra pagina dentro do meu site, sem ter que fazer Logout..

Comment: Isto é típico de sistemas mal pensados. Aqui por exemplo nunca precisamos dar *logout*. Também não precisamos dar *refresh* na página para ver algo que acabamos de alterar quando isto é importante. Há casos que trocar de página para ver a alteração não faz diferença, é algo desejável. De qualquer forma não há uma pergunta aí. pra falar a verdade eu teria dificuldade de reproduzir a situação que obrigasse *relogar* para atualizar.

Comment: Se você armazena o nome do usuário na sessão é só atualizar lá também depois de atualizar no banco. Não existe necessidade do usuário logar novamente.

Comment: O problema é que eu edito atraves do `PHPMYADMIN` mas eu tenho que dar logout e login para ele atualizar a informação ..

Comment: Coloque essa informação na pergunta, para deixa-la mais clara. Mas desse jeito não sei de outra maneira de atualizar sem dar _refresh_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, se você armazena o nome na sessão, você terá que alterar nela também.

Comment: O problema é que eu edito atraves do `PHPMYADMIN` mas eu tenho que dar logout e login para ele atualizar a informação ..